# Python Robot Framework - get_webelements returns wrong list

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

The website I am testing has a table which needs to be checked for sorting. I am able to get the items in the first column (the default state is sorted by ascending). When a column's header is clicked, the contents in the column is sorted again in reverse (e.g. ascending to descending). We are using the Robot Framework and the language used is Python.

To simplify, my code does this.
1st scenario (this is correct)

1. Perform a get web elements on the 1st column. (store in list A)
2. A list which is sorted by ascending is returned.
3. When the items in A is printed, the order is correct (ascending)

2nd scenario (this is the part where I am facing the issue)

1. Perform a get web elements on the 1st column (store in list A)
2. Click column header to sort the 1st column by ascending.
3. Perform a get web element son the 1st column (store in list B)
4. When both A and B's items are printed they are in descending order.

I am thinking there is a race condition happening so I also tried inserting a wait before and after clicking the column header but I am still getting descending order list for both steps 1 and 3 for the 2nd scenario.

This is the code for the scenarios above.

```
    self.asserts.verify_element_visible(self.data['locators']['segment_name_asc'], 'true', False)
    ele_asc = self.steps.get_elements(self.data['locators']['segment_name'])
    self.steps.click_element(self.data['locators']['segment_h1'])
    self.asserts.verify_element_visible(self.data['locators']['segment_name_desc'], 'true', False)
    ele_desc = self.steps.get_elements(self.data['locators']['segment_name'])

    for a in ele_asc:
        print a.text

    for d in ele_desc:
        print d.text
```

Comment: When you run the test and inspect it visually, the sorting actually happens in the UI, before the second Get Webelements?

Comment: The sorting happens in the ui and I can see the elements change inside the div when I click the header.